# How to gitignore parent folder while keeping subfolders to help python interpreter find created modules?

Tags: python-3.x, git, airflow, gitignore

Assuming I have the following git repo for an Airflow app

```
dags/
├── dag1.py
└── dag2.py
custom_packages/
├── package_1.py
└── package_1.py
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

The problem is that in the airflow server the project is inside a root folder called DPT_project. So everytime, in my local development interface, I need to call DPT_project.custom_packages.package_1.some_function to the code properly work in the airflow server.

How should be my .gitignore in my development enviroment in order that the interpreter work to help finding the modules and submodules that I created in custom_packages?

So far I've tried (after creating the folder DPT_project and tossing every file/folder inside):

```
DPT_project/*
!DPT_project/custom_dags/
!DPT_project/custom_packages/
!DPT_project/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

And it still copied the DPT_project folder to the git repository.
Any other suggestion is really welcomed. Also, I can change anything in the airflow server.

Comment: Your `.gitignore` content does not match the hierarchy that you sketched at the top of the post (it does not show `DTP_project` anywhere). Where is it and where do you place the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: As I sad in the comment before the gitignore script: "after creating the folder DPT_project and tossing every file/folder inside". DPT_project folder was created in the root directory. After creating it, the python interpreter works fine, but the airflow in the server do not reconize this project structure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by cloning the project in a local folder using the following command:

```
git clone <my repository https> DPT_project
```

adding DPT project will clone the project inside the folder DPT_project and the interpreter will recognize the created modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).